# How do I enter my password in Terminal?

Tags: command-line

I'm on a 2009 macbook pro dual boot. When my system starts, I get a message saying I don't have the wireless driver I need. I tried following the instructions from the website shown, but after I execute the command in Terminal, it asks for my password but will not allow me to type it in, so I have not been able to advance past that step.

This is my first time running Linux/Ubuntu on my computer so please be explicit :) Thanks

Comment: We would love to see which device you have before you install the possibly wrong driver or firmware. Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run: lspci -nn -d 14e4:  Edit your question to add the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, when a program asks you for password it is normal for the letters you type not to be shown for security reasons. If that is your problem simply type your password and press enter. :)